# Fully disable mouse in console Vim

Tags: bash, mouse

I saw [completely disable mouse in console Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684483/completely-disable-mouse-in-console-vim) on Stack Overflow.  It sounded like exactly what I wanted, but there the problem was related to Cygwin, so the title was a misnomer.

I want to know how to *completely* disable *all* mouse interactions in Vim on the console.  I don't want scrolling, selecting, clicking, or otherwise looking at the mouse to have any effect within Vim.

I like having the mouse in the console, just not when I'm using Vim.  Is this possible?

I have a laptop with Ubuntu installed on it and when I type, occasionally the touch pad mouse decides to randomly click or drag between some random coordinates on the screen, even when I try my hardest not to touch the damned thing.  This has the effect of me typing code in the wrong places all the time, and it's getting really old because sometimes it introduces subtle irreversible bugs into my code.

I've been able to get rid of scrolling and visual select using the commands below in my `.vimrc`, but it still will relocate the cursor when I click.

```
" disable mouse interactions "
set mouse=nicr
map <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
```

What else do I need to do?

P.S. I tried `set mouse=`, but that seems to reenable visual select...

Comment: `set mouse=` effectively disables *every* mouse interaction *with Vim*, but not with your terminal emulator. Are you sure that "visual select" is Vim's?

Comment: This could be due to loading a central configuration _after _ loading the config in `/etc/vimrc`. See my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506723/194822

Answer (score 61):

You should add the following two lines at the end of /etc/vim/vimrc :

```
set mouse=
set ttymouse=
```

Comment: +1 for `ttymouse`, all websites were mentionning `mouse` but `ttymouse` was the one I was missing. Thanks !

Comment: Crazy thing is that, when inside the editor, issuing `:set mouse-=a` works just fine. However, within the vimrc file only `set ttymouse=` does the trick. Why is that? Anyway: Thanks for the ttymouse from me as well.

Comment: `set ttymouse=` breaks the auto resize of vim when I resize my terminal emulator (terminator)

Comment: @on8tom did you try with another terminal emulator? Maybe it is a bug on their side?

Comment: the same goes for gnome-terminal but setting `set mouse=`  in `/usr/share/vim/vim82/defaults.vim` fixes it. but that also disables all mouse whithout setting `set ttymouse=`

Comment: +1 Simply running `:set mouse=` inside of my active `vim` session was enough to get puTTY's right-click paste to work properly.  (`:set paste` is also a good idea...)

Comment: I did all of them, it did not work. I was in a screen session where only one of my virtual ttys worked so badly. `reset` did not fix anything. I closed that tty and reopened it, that did the trick. **Then I started vim again, and that made the tty bad again, neither exiting vim, and reset helped.** I do not know, what to do. It seems there is a serious problem both in vim and in my teminal emulation.

Answer (score 5):

This might work if you put it at the end of your .vimrc

`set mouse=c`

It's probaly not Vim that takes the mouse input, but rather your Terminal-emulator. To disable mouse support on your terminal [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44513/disabling-mouse-support-in-vim-in-a-gnome-terminal-environment) might help.

Comment: Why `c` and not completely blank?

Comment: This worked for me when using `vim` over `ssh` (to a `Debian` `Bookworm` remote host) via `xterm`. Correct as per the docs at https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#mouse-using

Comment: Disabling Mouse Reporting in iTerm2 fixed this issue for me. Thanks for the steering @gustav

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution at best, but you can globally disable the mouse/touchpad while vim is running with `xinput` in a shell script:

```
xinput set-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 0
```

And then

```
xinput set-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 1
```

When you're ready to have the touchpad work again.

Use `xinput --list` to get the id of your pointing device.

Comment: This might combine well with the `FocusGained` and `FocusLost` autocommand events, though it looks like it there might be some challenge in finding a terminal + Vim setup where those events can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-C` flag

```
vim -C somefile
```

Comment: Welcome to this site @quant2016! Your answer was flagged as low quality because of its length. It would be useful for future readers that you explain why `-C` is a solution. Note that this flag doesn't only disable the mouse but it sets the compatible mode of vim which has _a lot_ of unattended side effect here, so I think that this should really be mentioned because it could cause more issues than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Even with

```
set mouse=
set ttymouse=
```

and the various mouse scroll 'key' bindings mapped to `<nop>` I was still having issues where the scroll wheel was moving the cursor.

I think what is going on is that the terminal is sending up/down keys instead of mouse scrolls.  In my case I'm using gnome-terminal with tmux inside.

I couldn't work out how to switch the mouse off more in tmux (it's already off!) and gnome-terminal doesn't seem to have a setting to control this.

For my purposes making up/down do nothing in normal mode does what I want.  Bear in mind this also stops you using the up/down keys to move the cursor which you might not like.

You might want to also do this in other modes but probably not command mode since up/down let you cycle through history in there!

```
"seems that either tmux or gnome-terminal converts scroll into up/down key presses
:nmap <Up> <Nop>
:nmap <Down> <Nop>
```