# How to disable mouse scroll wheel when in normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode, mouse, original-vi, set

I want to completely disable the mouse but mouse scrolling in normal mode is not disabled. I have disabled other mouse function but scrolling in normal mode is still on.

To disable the mouse I have used `set mouse=` and `ttymouse=`

Comment: Possibly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13566/18609

Comment: It is not related. It doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: did you try the maps in the question by any chance? Do they by any chance do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and after some fiddling around found that what is going on is that the terminal is sending up/down keys instead of mouse scrolls.

For my purposes making up/down do nothing in normal mode does what I want.  Bear in mind this also stops you using the up/down keys to move the cursor

You might want to also do this in other modes but probably not command mode since up/down let you cycle through history in there.

```
"seems that either tmux or gnome-terminal converts scroll into up/down key presses
:nmap <Up> <Nop>
:nmap <Down> <Nop>
```