# How to disable mouse in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, mouse

I'm on Arch Linux with [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty), zsh and neovim nightly (`NVIM v0.5.0-dev+1069-g02a966386`). I've read several posts on disabling the mouse in vim including [13566](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13566/fully-disable-mouse-in-console-vim) and have put the following in my `init.vim`

```
" disable mouse
map <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
map <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
set mouse=
```

I've also tried `set ttymouse=` but nvim complains `E518: Unknown option: ttymouse=`.

With the above settings, the cursor still moves when I scroll.

How do I fully disable mouse actions in neovim?

Answer (score 7):

For those googling, the option name in neovim is just `mouse`:

```
set mouse=
```

Comment: In Lua: `vim.opt.mouse = ""` – https://stackoverflow.com/a/76845374/2619107.